# From $42$ employees $7$ are very good at their job, $21$ are good and the rest are beginners

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

After we choose randomly two from them say $A$ and $B$ we observe that $A$ is better then $B$. What is the probability that $A$ is very good?

I am not certain if it is $\frac{7}{42}$ or $\frac{7}{41}$.
What do you say?

Comment: Neither.  Read the question again.  We have selected two people and observed that one is noticeably better than the other.  It might have been that $A$ was very good and $B$ was just normally good, it might have been that $A$ was very good and $B$ was a beginner, it might have been that $A$ was normally good and $B$ was a beginner.  How many of these scenarios exist?  Confirm for yourself that these scenarios you counted are equally likely.  Find the ratio of the number of these scenarios where $A$ was very good to the total number of scenarios that we might be in.

Comment: Thanks @JMoravitz

Comment: I would split it into three cases, assuming that employees are considered equivalent within a respective tier. Case 1: B is "very good". Case 2: B is "good". Case 3: B is "beginner".

If B is "very good", then A cannot be better than B.

If B is "good", then A might be better than B if A is "very good" but not "good" or "beginner".

If B is "beginner", then A might be better than B if A is "very good" or "good" but not "beginner".

Can you turn these into probabilities? Can you then combine these probabilities?

Comment: @CameronWilliams : "I would split it into three cases"...I think that two cases are enough

Comment: @tommik This is true as my explanation shows, but for someone who is newish to probability/combinatorics, it is best to be as clear as possible. Tricks come later.

Comment: the probability is the number of favourable outcomes divieded by the number of possible outcomes. What are the possible outcomes, what are the favourable outcomes?

Comment: Start with a smaller number of people: two very good people (v1,v2), two good people (b1,b2), two beginners(b1,b2). List all possible outcomes, list all favourable outcomes.

Comment: Is it (28/42) + (7/42)?

Comment: No, it is not, and it doesn't correspond to any useful probability in this scenario either.

Answer (score 0):

Given that we selected $A$ and $B$ and $A$ is noticeably better than $B$ at their job we are in one of the following three scenarios:

- $A$ was very good and $B$ was normally good
- $A$ was very good and $B$ was a beginner
- $A$ was normally good and $B$ was a beginner

Now... we count how many possibilities there are for each of these scenarios.  There are $7$ options for a very good person to be person $A$ and $21$ options for a normally good person to be person $B$.  There are then $7\times 21$ ways to have picked a very good person and a normally good person, so there are $7\times 21$ possible outcomes for who person $A$ and person $B$ are in this subcase.

Similarly, there are $7\times (42-7-21)=7\times 14$ outcomes in the second case and $21\times 14$ in the third case.

Altogether, there are $7\times 21+7\times 14 + 21\times 14$ different ways in which we may have randomly selected a person $A$ and a person $B$ such that person $A$ was noticeably better than person $B$.

Note that these different ways are indeed going to be equally likely to have occurred, which is what allows us to continue and calculate probabilities using ratios of good counts over total counts.

The number of favorable outcomes where $A$ was better than $B$ and where $A$ was very good will be the first two cases, so $7\times 21 + 7\times 14$.

The probability is the ratio of these:

$$\dfrac{7\times 21 + 7\times 14}{7\times 21 + 7\times 14 + 21\times 14}=\dfrac{245}{539}=\dfrac{5}{11}$$

Comment: Since only a *probability* has been asked for, an obvious "trick" would be to divide all the figures by $7$, thus $1$ very good, $3$ good and $2$ beginners.